# searching nearby available bluetooth in Xamarin android 9

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, bluetooth, android-9.0-pie

I want to search for available bluetooth but I can't find a solution that works in Xamarin android 9,

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, add the following permissions to **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

And for Bluetooth scan you could use the plugin **Plugin.BLE** from Nuget .

#### Usage

```
ObservableCollection<Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Contracts.IDevice> deviceList;


deviceList = new ObservableCollection<Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Contracts.IDevice>();
var adapter = CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;

adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
{
   Console.WriteLine(a.Device.Name);
   deviceList.Add(a.Device);
};
await adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();
```

For more details and usage of the plugin you could check https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le .